# Error using RSAGA multi.local.function - incompatible input grids

Tags: raster, r, ascii, gam

I'm trying to apply a gam model (called "modelo" below) to a stack of grids using multi.local.function through RSAGA, just like in the following code.

```
multi.local.function(in.grids = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g"), out.varnames = "modelado",fun = grid.predict, control.predict = list(type = "response"), fit = modelo)
```

"a","b","c","d","e","f","g" are ASCII grid files, all with the same pixel size, projection and position.

But, I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in multi.local.function(in.grids = c("a", "b",  : 
incompatible input grids
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
Two of my grids had only one extra pixel, and that made them incompatible.
That happened because they were originally points, and were converted to grids after that.

multi.local.function worked after I recliped the grid files using exactly the same polygon.
So I strongly recommend users to choose grids with a bigger coverage area, and to clip all of them with the same polygon/criteria after that.